# Centering a text above a vector icon on React native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to center a text above a vector icon (display 7 over a calendar icon ) , i'm using react-native-vector-icon, i tried with position absolute but no luck till now

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
   <Icon name='ios-calendar-outline' style={styles.iconStyle}/>
   <Text style={{position: 'absolute', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}></Text>
 </View>
```

is it possible to do such thing ?!

Comment: These references may or may not be helpful:
https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/04/react-native-layout-tricks/ , 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#layout-with-flexbox

Comment: Did you solve it? I wish you shared it if you solved since I am having the same issue and there are no correct answers on this topic

Answer (score 1):

[`Icon`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#styling) component from `react-native-vector-icon` built on top of the `Text` component. From [container](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#containers!) section of the `Text` component we have:
*elements inside of a  are no longer rectangles, but wrap when they see the end of the line*. So, when you add `Icon` and `Text` components in one `View`, they added to gather as one `text` component. It's a good idea to add a `View` wrapper for at least one of them:

```js
<View style={{alignItems: 'center',  justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:'blue'}}>test1</Text>
    <View>
        <Icon name='ios-calendar-outline' style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}/>
   </View>
</View>
```

**Update:**

You can see it on [*Expo*](https://snack.expo.io/r1hsRUJkW)

Comment: They aren't centered?

Comment: No they aren't .

Comment: I have just removed unused styles & add it to Expo. It's working there.

Comment: i'm asking about centering text above a vector icon , your link show it centered under the icon .

Comment: You need to change their order, as i changed it.

Comment: can you share your expo url ?

Comment: I had update both the answer & expo. Expo link updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this [on the simulator and pasted screensho](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#layout-with-flexbox)t.

Replace `<Image>` with `<Icon>` and wrap it in a `<View>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class AlignItemsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `alignItems` to 'flex-start'
      // Try setting `justifyContent` to `flex-end`.
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
        <Text>Put Icon inside a View</Text>
        <View>
          <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AlignItemsBasics);
```

You can edit code and test it out here:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#layout-with-flexbox

Pretty cool.  I did not know the Facebook doc code samples were basically live simulators!  You can edit code and add components.

[image: ent]

These references may or may not be helpful:

- https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/04/react-native-layout-tricks/
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#layout-with-flexbox
- https://github.com/dabbott/react-native-web-player
- https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Answer (score 0):

This is working, (Just add 'top:11')

```
    <View
      style={{
        alignItems: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Icon
        name="certificate"
        size={50}
        type="font-awesome"
        color="black"
        containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 14 }}
      />
      <Text
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          alignItems: "center",
          alignSelf: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          color: "white",
          top: 11,
        }}
      >
        1
      </Text>
    </View>
```